# Bluetooth keeps "hanging" after a few minutes

Tags: 16.04, mouse, bluetooth

I have a bluetooth mouse (MX Master) that connects via bluetooth directly (I don't even have its dongle anymore). Connection establishes instantly without issue on reboot and the mouse works fine for a few minutes. Then, the bluetooth subsystem seems to hang. Restarting the bluetooth service has no notable effect (and takes a long time to cycle as well). However, if I go into bluetoothctl and issue a "power off" (then wait for 15 seconds for it to acknowledge) and then do a "power on", it picks up the mouse immediately and everything is fine. That is, for another several minutes. If I try to open the device directly while its in the dead state, it simply fails without any meaningful error information. I must "power off/power on" and then it is okay for a few minutes.

There are times when it works fine for the whole day or several hours, but this hasn't been my luck the last couple of days.

When it is in its "dead" state, the mouse indicates that it is not connected, the status bar on the top right lists it as available, but when you go into the mouse's bt setting, the connection switch is grayed out - cannot change its position. The only solution that I know of is to either reboot the computer is power cycle the controller in bluetoothctl.

This is really frustrating. I have searched for people having this issue but they are always unrelated (usually audio stops, etc.), which, may be the case for me too, but the only device I have to test with is the mouse.

Incidentally, I use the mouse every day on my Windows work computer. It works flawlessly. The problem isn't the mouse.

I am running Ubuntu 16.04, bluetoothctl says my controller is ChromeLinux_8B18

Another thing: when it goes "dead", the little lock icon still remains on the status bar's bt icon (inidcating that it is connected to the mouse) even though the mouse is now turned off and put away. It will stay like this until I reboot or power cycle the controller).

EDIT: output from: `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb`

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:1010]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c018 Logitech, Inc. Optical Wheel Mouse
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 5986:055c Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Thanks

Comment: Is it a built-in bluetooth adapter or some USB dongle?

Comment: It is built-in. I don't have anything plugged in to any of the USB ports..

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 - updated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disabling "bluetooth coexistence technology" may fix the issue. It is no good in `iwlwifi`. Run in a terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/disable-btcoex.conf <<< "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N"
```

and reboot.

Comment: I fixed a typo in the command.

Comment: right after you posted your answer, I ran the command, noticed the failure with the typo and ran it again and rebooted. Then ran off to run a bunch or errands (against my will). So far, the mouse is still functional. I am going to keep an eye on it today and see how it goes. Curious about this bluetooth coexistence technology and why it is intent on draining the happiness from my life.

Comment: BT stops when you are using Wi-Fi. In other driver it works well, on Intel it is a problem.

Comment: If you have `/etc/modprobe` directory because of my typo, you can remove it by `sudo rm -r /etc/modprobe`. `modprobe.d` should stay BE CAREFUL.